# Interacting with Moodle API client to get quiz by course id

Tags: go, oauth-2.0, moodle, moodle-api

How can I interact with Moodle Api clients to get to quizzes by course id. The documentation says the mod_quiz_get_quizzes_by_courses requires a courseids array, but I don't know how to pass the array to the to Get request.

[image]

Comment: You at least could learn from their code on how to call API endpoints right?

Comment: Thanks, @zerkms, for the message. I can use most of the Moodle API client, but I am having difficulty doing the same for the mod_quiz_get_quizzes_by_courses function call.

Comment: Then you probably should ask about it explicitly and in details?

Comment: From the documentation on Moodle, if you don't pass an array, then all quizzes that you have access to will be returned https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_service_API_functions#:~:text=mod_quiz_get_quizzes_by_courses

Answer (score 1):

You can add course IDs to your request like this:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| `courseid[0]` | `3465` |
| `courseid[1]` | `5743` |
| `courseid[2]` | `4738` |

The brackets have to be encoded in the request.

Source: https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-50546